# Parse Push with only deviceToken

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

What is the minimum number of steps I have to take to send a push notification? I am already getting the deviceToken natively through iOS, do I have to create an Installation object through Parse? I would rather not change any native code right now. Can I do something like below? Or is creating the installation object required before this step? Below is using a node library.. but just imagine it is using REST endpoints.

```
var notification = {
  where : {
     "deviceToken": { 
        "$in": ["deviceTokenHere"] 
      }
  },
  data: {
    alert: "eat drink and be merry"
  }
};
this.client.sendPush(notification, function(err, resp){

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need an Installation object. The implementation on the backend side queries the Installations collection and you can't change this.

Adding the code is to create the Installation and store the token is pretty straight forward and does not require much code:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [installation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [installation saveInBackground];
}
```

If you currently store the deviceToken you already receive on your server, you can also create the installations via the [REST-API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#installations-uploading).